# is sequelize migrations file a need when using sequelize Associations?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Do you need Sequelize CLI migrations file to work with sequelize associations? or can you use associations without having a migrations file?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you are adding new tables in and they are associated to other tables, you need to included that in your migration file.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm trying to accomplish. I have 4 tables that are associated with one table by a foreign key.

Comment: If you post your tables, and your migration file I may be able to help you with the implementation (if you're stuck)

Comment: well right now I'm doing it without a migration file and when I enter information through my API the foreign key in the table displays "NULL"